# How to add R server job in HDInsights cluster for Ondemand cluster using Azure DataFactory

Tags: python, r, azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

How can we add R code as job in HDInsights on demand cluster ? 
Just as we can add Hive Job to run in HDInsights cluster , Is there a way to do R Scripts or Python . Here i want to use R , suppose if we want to include additional packages , how can we do it ?

Similarly can we do for python?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to run R/Python scripts as job on Azure HDInsight. There are some tutorials below which introduce how to get start.

For using R server, please see the tutorial [Get started using R Server on HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-r-server-get-started) and its `Next steps` section for more details.

Similarly for using Python, please see [Develop Python streaming programs for HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-streaming-python) and its extension links.

However, your question is too broad. If you can detail your needs, it can help us understanding and support more valuable helping for you.

Comment: Pan  Thanks for the Response .

Comment: Pan  Thanks for the Response .
But Iam looking for is , I want to automate the all jobs on Weekly basis , sequence of jobs like a) running a stored procedure in sql database b) Then cleaning data and feature engineering in HDInsghts cluster(Using R or Python ) to genarate master data that will be stored in sqldatabase [This cluster will take Jar file from Azure blob storage] c) Then running ML in Azure ML studio
For all these steps If i keep HDInsights cluster idle for week that will be costly So I want to use OnDemand compute HDI cluster for this purpose. And Use Azure DataFactory.